# Sorting a Matrix by Row in C

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, row

I have been asked to sort each row of a matrix given the number of rows, number of columns, and a pointer to the first element of the matrix (top left element). Here is the full question: [Homework Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j6L3.png)

So far I've been able to come up with this code:

```
void SortRowsOfMatrix(int rows, int columns, float* first_element) {
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
         for (int k = j + 1; k < columns; ++k) {
           if (first_element[i + j] > first_element[i + k]) {
             float temp = first_element[i + j];
             first_element[i + j] = first_element[i + k];
             first_element[i + k] = temp;
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

After tracing through the code by hand, I am noticing that the function will sort the first row of a matrix, but only the first row. I've tried modifying the code to sort the remaining rows, but so far I have had no luck.

Comment: For starters, your indexing e.g. `first_element[i + j]` is incorrect. It should be smth like `first_element[i * columns + j]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue!

Comment: You are only accessing the first row which goes from `first_element[0]` to `first_element[columns - 1]`. The second row goes from `first_element[columns]` to `first_element[2*columns - 1]`, the third row goes from `first_element[2*columns]` to `first_element[3*columns - 1]`, do you start to see the pattern here? The `n`th (counting from 0) row goes from `first_element[n*columns]` to `first_element[(n+1)*columns -1]`. With this info you should be able to fix your indices.